# MATLAB: Datetick at even monthly intervals

Tags: matlab

I want to mark my time series at even monthly intervals from Jan 2008 to Jan 2011.

**EDIT: The time series already has a time component in datenum format:**

```
733408 x1
733410 x2
etc...
```

**I apologize for not making this clear in my original statement of the question.**

A straightforward twice-annually implementation becomes incredibly messy:

```
years = [2008 2008 2009 2009 2010 2010 2011];
months = [1 7 1 7 1 7 1];
days = ones(1,7);
for k = 1:7
    dates(k) = datenum(years(k), months(k), days(k));
end
labels = datestr(dates,'mmm-yy');
set(gca,'XTick',dates);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',labels);
```

To expand this to monthly ticks:

```
years = [2008 ...repeat10times 2009 ...repeat10times 2010 ...repeat10times 2011]
m = 1:11; months = repmat(m,1,3)
days = ones(1:34)
```

There must be a simpler way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before converting your serial date numbers to dates you will need to set your axes ticks.

I just plotted some random numbers vs date as an example:

```
date1 = datenum([2012 01 01 00 00 00]);
date2 = now;
dateV = date1:date2; % x-axis data
y = rand(length(dateV),1); % y-axis data
hl = plot(dateV,y);
hax = get(hl, 'Parent'); % axes handle
```

By setting XTick property of the axes like this, ticks will be placed for every 30th element of dateV. You can change this to suit your tick intervals.

```
set(hax, 'XTick', [dateV(1:30:end)]); 
datetick('x', 24, 'keepticks'); 24 is a date format identifier. You can select a format from the datetick documentation.
```

As the [datetick](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) documentation points out, you need to set the axis ticks before you run the datetick function.

Answer (score 5):

Do you know `datetick`? For your example:

```
% date (x-data)
years = [2008 2008 2009 2009 2010 2010 2011];
months = [1 7 1 7 1 7 1];

% do plot (NOTE: datenum is vectorized!)
plot( datenum(years, months,1),  [your y-data] )

% set axis labels
datetick('x','mm-yyyy')
```

Or, a bit more general,

```
% generate periodic data
[years, months] = meshgrid(2008:2011, 1:12); % or whatever range you want

% do plot and set axes
plot( datenum(years(:), months(:), 1),  [your y-data] )
datetick('x','mm-yyyy')
```

Comment: All right I'll give that a try. Thanks. But to expand that to each-monthly ticks would mean repeating 2008 11 times, 2009 11 times, etc, in the years vector. Any simple way to make this vector?

Comment: @janon128: try my second example. That's exactly what it does :)

Comment: It works for a time series with one data point per mark?
I apologize for not making it clear in my original question that the time series I'm working with already has a time component in "datenum" format. 733408 (corresponding to Jan 1 2008)...etc all the way to Dec 31 2011.